# How can I shorten the code with FOR and İF structure?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I am looking for another alternative code. Kodum çok uzun.

```
Question_No <-c(1,1,1,1,1,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11)
Reply<-c("never","few","medium","much","complete",
             "never","few","medium","much","complete",
             "never","few","medium","much","complete")
Number_of_Answers<- c(7,1,12,13,18,6,2,12,10,21,6,2,13,11,19)
aa<- data.frame(Question_No,Reply,Number_of_Answers)
replace<- function(x)
    {Replys=x['Reply'] 
    if(Replys=="few"){return(2)}
    else if(Replys=="much"){return(4)} 
    else if(Replys=="never"){return(1)}
    else if(Replys=="medium"){return(3)}
    else {return(5)}}
  Replys<- apply(aa,MARGIN = 1,FUN = replace)
  aa['Replys']<-Replys
  aa= mutate(aa,NA_R = aa$Replys * aa$Number_of_Answers)

   aa$result = ifelse(aa$Question_No == 1,  sum(aa[1:5,5]),
                ifelse(aa$Question_No == 10, sum(aa[6:10,5]),
                ifelse(aa$Question_No == 11, sum(aa[11:15,5]),"n")))
```

My code is too long. Is there more useful code with For and IF instead of IFELSE?

Comment: Take a look at `?switch` especially the Examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the code needs **stucture** and **generalization**, so I hope that the following part of the answer can give you an idea how to solve it in full. One method to avoid repeated if's is to use a dictionary and then a database join. R has several match and join functions, the example uses `left_join` from **dplyr**:

```
library("dplyr")

df <- data.frame(
  Question_No = c(1,1,1,1,1,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11),
  Reply = c("never","few","medium","much","complete",
           "never","few","medium","much","complete",
           "never","few","medium","much","complete"),
  Number_of_Answers = c(7,1,12,13,18,6,2,12,10,21,6,2,13,11,19)
)

dictionary <- data.frame(
  Reply = c("never", "few", "medium", "much", "complete"),
  result = 1:5
)

df2 <- left_join(df, dictionary, by="Reply")
df2
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option

```
aa <- transform(
  transform(
    aa,
    Reply = c(2, 4, 1, 3, 5)[match(
      Reply,
      c("few", "much", "never", "medium", "compelete")
    )]
  ),
  NA_R = Reply * Number_of_Answers
)
```

gives

```
> aa
   Question_No Reply Number_of_Answers NA_R
1            1     1                 7    7
2            1     2                 1    2
3            1     3                12   36
4            1     4                13   52
5            1     5                18   90
6           10     1                 6    6
7           10     2                 2    4
8           10     3                12   36
9           10     4                10   40
10          10     5                21  105
11          11     1                 6    6
12          11     2                 2    4
13          11     3                13   39
14          11     4                11   44
15          11     5                19   95
```